# Node.js - Mongodb connection in master or forked thread

Tags: node.js, multithreading, mongodb, mongoose

When using the Node.js cluster library, should a connection to MongoDB via `require('mongoose').connect()` be made in the master thread or in each child thread. If `connect()` is called in each thread, is the same connection returned to each of the threads or a different connection? If each thread gets a new connection, does having an independent connection to MongoDB in each thread increase resilience of the system?

Fundamentally, should each thread have it's own connection to MongoDB?

Comment: Can someone please answer this question?